# Can I stop a user closing my UWP application (Excluding End Task)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am designing a UWP application. On pressing the **"X" (close button)** I would like to display a popup to say *"You are about to close without saving. Would you like to discard your work?"* and cancel the close event if the user clicks *"No"*

Another way I have thought about doing this is hiding the **"X" (Close button)** completely so that the User can only close it using my own close button.

I am not worried about the "End Task" because there is nothing you can do about that anyway.

So is it possible to do either one of the following:

- Can I intercept the close event of the application and stop it?
- Can I hide the close button?

I know this is possible in WPF but is something similar available in UWP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible, you can do something similar for back button, but not for closing one. User just terminates the app and you can do nothing about it, note also that your app might have hanged and user still will be able to close it.

It's wort to mention that the app will still process some events like *Suspending* when user clicks 'X' - thus you still have a chance to save some things/process some logic.

More information about this you will find at [MSDN - section *App Close*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-close):

> There is not an event to indicate that the user closed the app. When an app is closed by the user, it is first suspended to give you an opportunity to save its state.